# Update highchart data using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I have a Highchart line chart in my jsp as follows.

```
$(function () {
chart2 = new Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        useUTC: false
    }
});
$('#patternContainer').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: 'Selected Pattern',
        x: -20 //center
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: {
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '°C'
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
    }]
});
```

});

And I want to change the graph data when click on a button. Here I called following ajax method to update data.

```
function getPatternData(){
$.ajax({
    success: function() {
        chart2.series[0].update({
            data: [0.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 100, 25.2, 0.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 0.6]
        });
    }
});
```

}

Can anyone please point me what's wrong here. 
here is the place i'm calling event in jsp

```
<li class="list-group-item liitem" onclick="javaScript:getPatternData()"><strong>${pattern.id}:</strong>
                                        <span class="pull-right"  >${pattern.name}</span>

                                    </li>
```

Comment: Where is the event for your button?

Comment: where did you find an update method for object in javascript?

Comment: Updated the question, onclick event added

Answer (score 1):

Remove the onclick() attribute in your HTML and replace it with this line in your JQuery script.

```
//You can add the ID or class associated with your button where
// button is stated below. 
$(document).on("click","button",function()
{
   getPatternData();
});
```

If you are loading anything from AJAX then there is a good chance that there are elements being appended to the DOM tree after initial DOM load, Meaning that they are not bound to the handler.